# HttpMessagehandler in a weatherforecast

Tags: c#, rest, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, message-handlers

I am trying to implement the `HttpMessageHandler` in the weather forecast example for ASP.NET Core Web API.

Basically I want a `HttpMessageHandler` class to intercept the `HttpRequest` before it hits the controller and again before sending the response to a client.

Just as the message inspector in WCF (`BeforeSend` and `AfterReceive`), but I cannot find a working example with the `WeatherForecast` .NET Core template.

How can I configure that my `MessageHandler` class?

```
public class MessageHandler1 : DelegatingHandler  
{  
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  
    {  
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)  
            {  
                Content = new StringContent("We got your request but did not process it !!")  
            };  

        var tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();  
        tsc.SetResult(response);  

        return await tsc.Task;  
    }
}
```

I can create this `MessageHandler1` class somewhere in my code, but how can I get it initialized? Do I use my startup `Program.cs`? And what code gets it activated in my rest API application?

Comment: Take a look at [DelegatingHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.delegatinghandler?view=net-7.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use `Program.cs` to inject your interceptor.
Inside `Program.cs` add you interceptor:

```
...
var app = builder.Build();

//HTTP response interceptor
app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();
...
```

then in your `MyMiddleware` interceptor do this next:

```
public class MyMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger<MyMiddleware> _logger;
    private readonly IHostEnvironment _environment;

    public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<MyMiddleware> logger, IHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
        _environment = environment;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            // do your stuff
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
            
            // do your stuff

            await context.Response.WriteAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Additional information you can find here: [Middleware Example](https://exceptionnotfound.net/using-middleware-to-log-requests-and-responses-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: I am trying to implement the MessageHandler feature and hook into the HTTP pipeline. Not to create my own middleware.

Comment: @codingjoe Why is this the accepted answer then?

Comment: @Alexander Because I went with this solution

Answer (score 1):

Just Like Scotty13 had pointed out in ASP.NET Core to intercept a request before it hits your controller you will need to use a middleware. Take a look at the [ASP.NET CORE request cycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

The [HttpMessageHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpmessagehandler?view=net-7.0) is a class at a lower level than middleware it can intercept **outgoing** HTTP requests and incoming responses . They work with [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0) and is primarily used in scenarios where you need to customize the behavior of **outgoing** HTTP requests or incoming HTTP responses.

Comment: Thanks for your input I am already working with it and it works as intended.